# How do I copy a file to the clipboard and paste it somewhere else?

Tags: vb.net, clipboarddata

I have a listview with small thumbnails of images.
Each image has a tag with it's full path in it.

With a rightclick menu the user can click COPY.

Then this code is excecuted:

```
Dim selectedfile As String

selectedfile = Me.lvFotos.SelectedItems(0).Tag


Dim dataobj As New DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, selectedfile)

Clipboard.Clear()
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataobj)
```

Now when I click on my desktop to paste the file I get an exception error in VS2010:

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
>
> Additional information: Invalid FORMATETC structure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040064 (DV_E_FORMATETC))

What am I doing wrong here?

rg.
Eric

Comment: `Clipboard.SetText(lvFotos.SelectedItems(0).Tag.ToString)` I am not sure what you are doing with the rest of that code...if you have the name of the file, use it.

Comment: How would that work when I don't know the destination up front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the code from John Smith at [Copying a File To The Clipboard](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/276982-copying-file-clipboard):

```
Dim f() As String = {"C:\temp\Folder.jpg"}
Dim d As New DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, f)
Clipboard.SetDataObject(d, True)
```

(Tested as working in VS2013 on Windows 7 x64.)

Note that you have to pass an array of strings representing your filename(s), so you could allow the user to gather several items before pasting, if you wanted to.

The `true` in `Clipboard.SetDataObject` allows the data to remain on the clipboard when you exit the program, so if the user were to select a file and exit before pasting, they would not have lost their selection.

Answer (score 4):

You could use directly [`My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36xbexyf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

```
Dim source As String = lvFotos.SelectedItems(0).Tag
Dim destination As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & from.Substring(from.LastIndexOf("\"))
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(source, destination)
```

Answer (score 1):

Found what I was doing wrong.

At first I had tried it with the name of the file in an array, but that gave the same error.

Now I have it like this:

```
 Dim selectedfile(0) As String

selectedfile(0) = Me.lvFotos.SelectedItems(0).Tag

Dim dataobj As New DataObject

dataobj.SetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, True, selectedfile)

Clipboard.Clear()
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataobj, True)
```

The difference is in the line with SETDATA.
By setting the second argument to TRUE in SetData and also in the SetDataObject, it started to work.